# Why did the show cut out these character arcs in season 5?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

It is apparent that the show writers/creators of *[Game of Thrones (HBO)](http://www.hbo.com/game-of-thrones#/)* have decided to cut the story-lines of:

> - **[Aegon VI Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen_%28son_of_Rhaegar%29)** (Young Griff) and his whole story arc, including:
>
>   - **[Jon Connington](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jon_Connington)** (Griff)
>   - **[Illyrio Mopatis](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Illyrio_Mopatis)**
>   - Septa **[Lemore](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lemore)**
>   - Ser **[Rolly Duckfield](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rolly_Duckfield)** (Duck)
>   - **[The Golden Company](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Golden_Company)**
>   - etc
> - The Greyjoys and the whole [Kingsmoot](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kingsmoot#A_Feast_for_Crows), including:
>
>   - [**Euron "Crow's Eye" Greyjoy**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Euron_Greyjoy)
>   - **[Victarion Greyjoy](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Victarion_Greyjoy)**
>   - **[Aeron (Damphair) Greyjoy](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aeron_Greyjoy)**
>   - **[Dragonbinder](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dragonbinder)**
>   - Victarion's mission to 'take' **[Daenerys](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daenerys_Targaryen)**
>   - etc
> - The Dornish Arc, including:
>
>   - **[Quentyn Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Quentyn_Martell)**
>   - **[Arianne Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Arianne_Martell)**
>   - [The Marriage Pact](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Secret_marriage_pact)
>   - etc

I have not found any official evidence of *why* they have done this. There's a lot of speculation<sup>[[1]](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2015/04/game-of-thrones-no-aegon-young-griff), [[2]](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/42465/20150327/game-of-thrones-season-5-7-big-changes-from-the-book-to-expect.htm)</sup>, but **What is the official reason these story-lines were cut from the show?**

Any word from D&D? Any word from GRRM? Any word from HBO?

Comment: My guess is "lack of time to do all storylines from the books" and "their arcs weren't necessary for the main plot". The same happened with a certain lady with an unusual heart.

Comment: You have to add the fact that they need (want) to keep emiting episodes, but it'll clearly take several years to GRRM to keep with the story. For that, HBO had decided to go on with their own version of the story from now on.

Comment: I think the cast would be to big to include every little side character, it is huge already for a TV show. But who knows, maybe the show keeps to be successful and they get the money to make a whole season with the left out arcs. Martin planned 7 books, who says the series must have 7 seasons. With the material already present, they could make 10 seasons easily or make more than 10 episodes per season...

Comment: I think the answer is pretty clear, and this might be a dupe btw. HBO don't want to lose any steam from the momentum of the series by following a single character in a long side arc without meeting high profile characters but instead introducing new ones. You see HBO goes by the concept of having at least 2-3 "main" characters per shot. That would be very difficult to maintain with Tyrion's trip with young Griff, or the Quentyn Martell journey to Meereen. It is sad though, but what can I say, HBO is in the business of making money, not making our dreams com true.

Comment: are all of these definitively cut, or could they be revisited in later series? HBO is all over the place in terms of the plotlines. For instance, they blasted through Bran's story by the end of the season and now have no material left for him. Other characters, have had roles and plotlines conflated with the arcs of other characters (e.g. Sansa replacing the fake Arya as Ramsay's bride in GOT the TV show), or been sidelined completely. Think Yondaime008 is onto something, but it does beg the question why Jojen, Meera and Hodor are considered major characters but others are not!

Comment: @yondaime008 - "HBO is in the business of making money, not making our dreams com true." No, it's in the business of making our dreams come true to the extent that it can do so without going bankrupt. It's the difference between amateur and professional artists: professionals need to get paid to keep on making art, amateurs do it in between making a living.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I was quoting GM CEO when he said "GM is in the business of making money not in the business of making cars" with a twist. Either way, you're right, GoT still is a major nerdgasm :D

Comment: @yondaime008 - Point to you. You got me.

Comment: Am I the only one that found those particular plots irritating and tiresome in the books?  Good riddance, I say.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's only one answer - **they're not essential (*yet?*) for the story HBO is telling**. HBO's priority is making that story into one which works on television, not preserving everything from the books.

I say "yet?" because, with the possible exceptions of Arianne and Quentyn (who appear to have gone the way of Garlan Tyrell), there's always the possibility they could be introduced with adapted stories should they become necessary. For example, I was convinced Ser Dontas had been written out of the show when he didn't repeatedly meet with Sansa  like in the books, and I was expecting someone like Brienne to do an adapted version of his role. Instead, he was reintroduced at the last minute, with a much shorter version of his story, with just enough context for the plot and no more.

**It all hinges on what happens in books unwritten**. We know that the show intends to very roughly follow the trajectory of the books GRRM hasn't written yet, which presumably means the fates of  the families overall and A-list characters like Dany and Tyrion will *broadly* match. Will Aegon, Euron, Victarion etc be irreplacable parts of this core story? If so, don't be surprised if they are rapidly introduced later - when they start to become essential, and no sooner.

Update now Season 6 is out:

> Euron has suddenly appeared, and rapidly reached a point similar to where he ends in A Dance With Dragons, ready to start taking a part in the main plot. 
>  
>  Interestingly, his actor is someone quite different to what many book readers expected - someone less suited to fearsome imposing villains, more associated with playing complex, troubled, ambiguous enigmas.

**This is why no-one involved in the show's production will *or should* comment**.  If they say, for example, that Connington is definitively cut,  ruling out the possibility of him making a surprise appearance, then that's a spoiler for books that haven't been written yet. It'd  strongly suggest that he's not going to have an irreplaceable role in the central story.